# AWS OpsWorks CLI - add an existing instance to a layer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks, aws-cli, amazon-ec2

I have been trying to find a way to achieve the following outcome by using the AWS cli.

My workflow that I currently use to achieve the desired outcome in the web interface is as follows:

1. Add a PHP Application Instance.
2. Add a MySQL Server Instance (On the Existing tab, select the PHP instance created in step 1).

This would essentially 'marry' the two, so they wouldn't just be two separate instances with separate IPS and etc.

I have tried a few things like creating two instances and then using "assign-instance" but I didn't have much luck there and cant figure out any other method of achieving this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?